# Refresh upon authenticated user, Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

I have setup a Private route for my Dashboard Pages, all the routes within the dashboard is working perfectly but anytime I do a Refresh in my private route, it doesn't save the user session, therefore navigates back to the login page. Although I did setup a function to deny access to the dashboard page if not authenticated but when the user is authenticated, I want it to store somewhere so that whenever the page gets refreshed it would have known it's an authenticated user..
Here's my Login and Private route;

Login-

```
  const signIn = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await login(email, password);
      navigate(from, { replace: true});
      setLoading(true);
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMessage(error, errorMessage)
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }
```

Private Route-

```
import { Outlet, Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom"
import { projectAuth } from "./firebase";


const PrivateRoute = () => {

  const location = useLocation();


  return projectAuth.currentUser ? (<Outlet />) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" state={{from: location}} replace/>
  )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

What I tried was to logout anyone that tries to hardcode the dashboard page if not authenticated. What I want to achieve is after being authenticated, I should store the user session somewhere to prevent authenticated users being logged out after a refresh. I'm using firebase currently for authentication

Answer (score 0):

In most browser-based environments Firebase already automatically stores the user credentials and restores them when the page reloads.

To detect this state, use an `onAuthStateChange` listener as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).